# Combining hyperref's label macro with tikz macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref

I would like to mark my labels visually. Trying to expand `hyperref`'s macro `\label` using the `\label@hook` gives me error messages and some weird behaviour.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\parindent=0pt

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labmarred}{\@bsphack\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \fill[red] (0,0.75ex) circle (4pt);\@esphack}
\renewcommand{\labmarred}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \fill[red] (0,0.75ex) circle (4pt);}

\AtBeginDocument{\preto{\label@hook}{\labmarred}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap 1}\label{chap:a}
\blindtext

\section{Sec 1}\label{sec:a}
\blindtext

\phantomsection\label{sec:a:a}
\blindtext

\labmarred
\blindtext

\subsection{Subsec 1}\label{subsec:a}
\blindtext

\subsection{Subsec 2}\label{subsec:b}
\blindtext

\subsection{Subsec 3}\label{subsec:c}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

There is a spurious indent of the first texxt line on every red dot except the one that has been inserted manually (line 27 by calling `\labmarred`) and several error messages of the type `Bad space factor (0).`

Both versions in the above example result in exactly the same as well as using the `tikz` environment instead of `\tikz` does.

The `showlabels` package and the `showkeys` version are using `\marginpar` which is often not at the right position.

Any hint where to go?

Comment: You shouldn't fiddle around with `\label@hook` but use the safer `\pretocmd{\label}{\labmarred}{}{}}`, in my point of view

Comment: A tikz drawing is a box, even if it has size zero, if will change the typesetting if you add it at this places.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer can't check at the moment but as far as I remember `\pretocmd` gives the same result (see comment of @Ulrike Fischer)

Comment: @AndiW: I can compile your example with my proposition at least, the indent is there anyway, but the compilation does not fail

Comment: @ChristianHupfer unfortunately here your solution fails at the last `\subsection`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @Ulrike Fischer that `\tikz` is embedded in a hbox i found the `tikzmark`-library that provides `\pgfmark` which is the same as the `\tikzmark` but without the `\hbox`. The following code works with some restrictions: From my point of view there is nothing wrong to use `\label@hook` since the label name is available and as far as I understand the hook-system hooks are designed just for that.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\parindent=0pt
\parskip=1ex

\makeatletter
\newcounter{markcnt}
\newcommand{\labmarred}{\global\addtocounter{markcnt}{1}%
  \pgfmark{dummy\arabic{markcnt}}\marginpar{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \fill[red] ($(pic cs:dummy\arabic{markcnt})-(0,3ex)$) circle (4pt);}}

%\AtBeginDocument{\pretocmd{\label}{\labmarred}{}{}}
\AtBeginDocument{\preto{\label@hook}{\labmarred}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap 1}\label{chap:a}
\blindtext

\section{Sec 1}\label{sec:a}
\blindtext

\phantomsection\label{sec:a:a}
\blindtext

\labmarred
\blindtext

\subsection{Subsec 1}\label{subsec:a}
\blindtext

\subsection{Subsec 2}\label{subsec:b}
\blindtext

\subsection{Subsec 3}\label{subsec:c}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Issues:

1. There is an y-shift of about `+3ex` I could not find the reason for so the `\tikz`-circle has to be shifted down to be at approximately the right position.
2. Since the circles are drawn in a `\marginpar` there is still an issue if the `\marginpar` is moved to the next page - It might be better to put that into the foot or the head of the page.

Anyway - I provide this one as an answer since it seems to be one possible way to go...

Thx to  @Christian Hupfer for the critical input and @Ulrike Fischer for the (hidden) hint where to go...

EDIT:

Due to the definitely inaccessible page break system of TeX even this scetchy solution will fail if there is a `\label` placed at the end of a paragraph which spans over several pages... In short: doesn't work as expected...